# Repeating n row numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, repeat

In postgresql syntax, `row_number()` can be used to generate incremental integers as in the example below.  How would one repeat these integers `n` times or until the row length runs out?  For example, using the following syntax, if the goal is to repeat each incremental integer 5 times, how could one generate the following output for `rownum_repeat` ? :

```
CREATE TABLE public.examples (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    public.examples (text)
VALUES
    ('val1'), ('val2'), ('val3'),  ('val4'), ('val5'), ('val6'), ('val7');

SELECT
    *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
FROM
    public.examples;


id  text    rownum rownum_repeat
1   "val1"  1      1
2   "val2"  2      1
3   "val3"  3      1
4   "val4"  4      1
5   "val5"  5      1
6   "val6"  6      2
7   "val7"  7      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the row number in the simple arithmetic:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)- 1) / 5+ 1 as rownum_repeat
FROM
    public.examples
ORDER BY id;
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/E67CyQtr)

Note that row numbers depend on sort order.